# Error in UseMethod("select") : no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"

Tags: r

I am getting the above error message when I input the following syntax:

```r
y <- mydata_final_distinct %>%
  select(Case_ID,starts_with (Effect_)) %>% 
   pivot_longer(-Case_ID, names_to='symptoms', values_to=adr) %>% 
   distinct(Case_ID,'symptoms',adr,.keep_all = TRUE) %>%
   count(adr) %>% 
   arrange(desc(n))
```

Comment: Please provide sample data with `dput(head(mydata_final_distinct))` or similar, sufficient to demonstrate the error and your desired output.

Comment: What is the output of `str(mydata_final_distinct)`?  Also, `select(Case_ID,starts_with (Effect_))` doesn't look right to me. Do you still get the same error if you replace that line with `select(Case_ID,starts_with("Effect_"))`?

Comment: The output for (mydata_final_distinct) is:
mydata_final_distinct<-mydata %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = c(Primary_Suspect_Drugs,Secondary_Suspect_Drugs,Other_Administered_Drugs,Adverse_Events,
                          Effect_1:Effect_367), .fns = tolower)) %>% 
  distinct(Case_ID,FDA_Date,Age,Gender,.keep_all = TRUE)

I am hoping this can give a clue. I tried the other suggestions above and they did not work. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is difficult to troubleshoot without having some of your data, I would first make the library explicit in the function calls, as it may be trying to use `select` from another library.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

y <- mydata_final_distinct %>%
  dplyr::select(Case_ID, starts_with (Effect_)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-Case_ID, names_to = 'symptoms', values_to = adr) %>%
  dplyr::distinct(Case_ID, 'symptoms', adr, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  dplyr::count(adr) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(n))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is helpful, however, I got a different error now:

Error: Internal error in `compact_rep()`: Negative `n` in `compact_rep()`. 

How would I resolve this one?

Comment: @tichawonachinzowu It's difficult to know without having some of your data to troubleshoot. Could you provide some of `my_data`? You can do `dput(head(my_data))` and it would only be 6 rows of the data. If you have any sensitive data, then you can always change them to something else. It honestly doesn't have to be your exact data. Just need data in the same structure to troubleshoot.

Comment: I want to apologise I am fairly new to R. I have created a csv file with six rows of mydata, but I  cannot figure out how to upload it on this platform. Thank you to all those helping. I really appreciate your patience.

Comment: @tichawonachinzowu You can go ahead and load the .csv into R, like `my_data <- read.csv("my_data.csv")`, then in the console do `dput(my_data)`. Then, you can just copy the results from that, and paste it into your original question (formatted as code). Then, I'll be able to recreate `my_data` and troubleshoot.